# QComboBox drop-down item margin

Tags: qt, qt5, qtgui, qtstylesheets, qabstractitemview

I want to style my `QComboBox` with margin for the drop down items. This is how it looks like now:

[image]

And I would like something like this:

[image]

I tried with

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {
    margin: 3px;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want set some space between items.I try different stylesheets, but I can't get result. But I found this solution. Maybe it helps.

```
    ui->comboBox->setView(new QListView());
ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item { min-height: 35px; min-width: 50px; }QListView::item:selected { color: black; background-color: lightgray}");
```

Result is very similar
[image]

Comment: This is very strange because I'm not getting what you get. I just created an empty project, dragged a QComboBox inside and pasted your code but it does not work. This is what I have: test.pro(http://pastebin.com/fihj8944), mainwindow.h(http://pastebin.com/qMiazMVd), mainwindow.cpp(http://pastebin.com/FnHdteZU), main.cpp(http://pastebin.com/fsDD1kFr) and mainwindow.ui(http://pastebin.com/NCjMsj43). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JacobKrieg , I carefully watch your code, but I don't see in your code ui->comboBox->setView(new QListView()); Add this line before setStyleSheet() . First ui->comboBox->setView(new QListView()); and after - setStyleSheet() (I hope you understand me). And after adding of this line it should work.

Comment: But I added the elements using the designer. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: In my designer I added it too, but without this line it doesn't works. Just add this line and you'll see that this work properly(I'm sure,because without this line my app don't want add this space)Moreover,with this line,it works properly when I add icons in the combobox. I think, that it is a solution,try this

Comment: You are right, indeed it worked. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Chernobyl, you're a genius!

Answer (score 2):

```
ui->comboBox->setItemDelegate(new QStyledItemDelegate());
```

also works