# Is there a way to change the height of the items of the drop down list of a QComboBox through the stylesheet?

Tags: qt5, qtstylesheets

I would like to have all the **comboboxes** of my application similar to the PyCharm ones. I was able to change the box itself but not the **drop-down list**.

**Here's what I would like to have:**

[image]

**Here's what I have:**

[image]

I would like to increase the **height** of the items, the **space** between them and to remove the **dotted** border when the mouse hovers the item. All of this using the **stylesheet**, since I want all `QComboBox` to be like this.

**Here's my stylesheet:**

```
QComboBox{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 8pt;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    padding: 3px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1px;
}

QComboBox:focus, QComboBox:on{
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(151, 195, 243);
    margin:0px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down{
    border:none;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow{
    right: 4px;
    image: url(:/custom/custom_icons/down-arrow.png);
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView{
    border: 1px solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {
    height: 50px;   /*not working*/
}
```

Comment: does that help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341456/166768 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/52779268/166768

Comment: @bzs That's not what I wanted because, as I said, I would like to set it just the first time and not everytime I'm using a QComboBox. But I think I will end up following those suggestions and trying to find the smarter way to apply the changes without getting crazy.